# JW Player Auto Pause On Wordpress

Tags: jwplayer

I have a wordpress site with a jwplayer but i want to know how can I auto pause it after 30 mins.

please help me with this problem

please be brief on the answer on where can i put the codes to work it properly

thank you

Comment: I'm afraid we do not have an auto pause feature.

Comment: Edit your question to ask something specific and programming-related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to interpret "after 30 minutes". If you want to do this after 30 minutes of calendar time:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    jwplayer().pause();
},30*60*1000);
```

If you want to do this when the 30 minute mark of a video is hit:

```
jwplayer().onTime(function(event){
    if(event.position >  30*60) {
        jwplayer().pause();
    }
});
```

Comment: ok thanks but one last question. Where should i put this code? should i simply add this code on the lower line?

Comment: You should be able to take the 2nd block of code, and paste it under your JW Player set up.

Comment: Thank you Ethan but I cannot find the JW Player setup on wordpress